# How to fix mail to particular contacts not appearing in Sent folder?

Tags: macos, mail.app

On Mountain Lion's Mail, I am having a problem with the messages I send to a particular coworker from my work account not appearing in the Sent mailbox.

- The messages **are** going through. (I got her to Fwd: the important one back to me.)
- Messages I sent to my other accounts, even from that account, are correctly appearing in Sent.
- Messages I send from another address (even using the same SMTP server) are appearing in Sent.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Connection Doctor. It shows no issues.
2. Deleting + recreating the account.
3. Rebuilding the mailbox.
4. I'm familiar with **Use This Mailbox For >** and it is not a factor here.

Any ideas?

Comment: A coworker has suggested this may just be a hosting glitch. The symptoms seemed unlikely, but IMAP does seem… complicated. (I believe SMTP is used to send, but IMAP is used to put the message in Sent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a hiccup on the SMTP server.